# Gantt diagram does not present the information

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I created a gantt diagram using a library from devextreme.
I am trying to store the information in just 2 datasources, which differs from the example of devextreme.
My problem is that the data is not shown in the diagram and I don't know where the problem is.

Someone can help me?
Thank you

[**Library**](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Gantt/DataBinding/Angular/Light/)

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wq5mid?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**HTML**

```
 <dx-gantt
    taskListWidth="500"
    scaleType="weeks"
    height="700"
    rootValue="-1">

    <dxo-tasks [dataSource]="Task"></dxo-tasks>
    <dxo-dependencies [dataSource]="Task"></dxo-dependencies>
    <dxo-resources [dataSource]="resources"></dxo-resources>
    <dxo-resource-assignments [dataSource]="Task"></dxo-resource-assignments>
    <dxi-column dataField="title" caption="Subject" [width]="300"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="start" caption="Start Date" dataType="date"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="end" caption="End Date" dataType="date"></dxi-column>
    <dxo-editing [enabled]="true"></dxo-editing>
</dx-gantt>
```